# How can i fetch data from local json file of multidimensional object

Tags: asp.net-web-api

how can i fetch data from local json file in react

Here is the sample data looks like

```
{
  "data": {
    "Table": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "first_name": "Alez"
    },
    {
      "id": "1002",
        "first_name": "Baro"
    }],

  }
}
```

Comment: `data_response_json___default.a.map ;` is not a function because you are probably not exporting anything from that .json file, also `import Something` expects a default export and `import {Something}` does not so that could be an issue as well....

Comment: @HolyMoly the original source of the the json data is from the API and its a nightmare to extract data  when the format is `{
  "data": {
    "Table": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "first_name": "Alez"
    },
    {
      "id": "1002",
        "first_name": "Baro"
    }],

  }
}` i get it to work when form data is like this `[

      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Alex",
        "last_name": "tora"
      },

      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Baro",
        "last_name": "tora"
      }
    ]` i am testing using the local copy to identify the proble

Comment: so i am clear? you are making a API request to get this data and parsing it to json if needed? then writing that to a .json file stored on the frontend?

Comment: yes, now i stored it as response.json file but originally i was trying to extract the data directly from the API url i have code here codepile.net/pile/gE3kx1Eo. does that make sense?

Comment: the way the data is, is actually not unusual, it's a object with a key of `Table` which has an array as it's value that you want to iterate...this is not 'bad' structure (though i don't like the capital T lol) ...it's actually is perfectly common. that said, i think your issue is that you are writing this big json object to a file that has no export, and importing it as if it is a component with a `default` import. Can you post your code where you are fetching the data and lets see if we can get that working the right way :)

Comment: Thanks!! API is accessble locally only but i added the code  in my question

Comment: is that a private key if so REMOVE IT RIGHT NOW

Comment: sorry it only accessible locall and  its  a sample,

Comment: phew! okay this is actually pretty close i think i may see what is wrong..if you log `results` from state...what do you get? I think you should get a `{}` with a key `Table` ... if you changed `results.map(results =>` to `results.Table.map(results =>` does it work?

Comment: i am going to create a answer and update it as needed so it's easier

Comment: can i test it using the local file? because i cant api is not accessible?

Comment: i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`, I tested `[

      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Alex",
        "last_name": "tora"
      },

      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Baro",
        "last_name": "tora"
      }
    ]` locally i can fetch using ` {PostData.map((postDetail, index) => {
                    return <h1>{postDetail.first_name}</h1>
                })}
`

Comment: guess what i able to fetch using `{PostData.data.Table.map((postDetail, index) => {
                    return <h1>{postDetail.first_name}</h1>
                })}`

Comment: yes i was just writing that out for you, but  i said that a couple comments above that you needed  `results.Table.map` lol  :)

Comment: you were trying to iterate on `data` but `data` is an object... srry that took a second for me to get to i was hung up on you trying to read from a file you were importing when it looked like you were not exporting the json obj.... and also hung up on the fact that you would need to write to a file in the first place lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so let's first export it from the json file for local testing, however you do not need to write it to a file assuming the API is accessible :)  but for now:

```
export const MyData = {
  "data": {
    "Table": [{
      "id": "1001",
      "first_name": "Alez"
    },
    {
      "id": "1002",
        "first_name": "Baro"
    }],
  }
}
```

import that into your file `import {MyData} from 'some-path'`

then you should be able to iterate it like:

```
function renderemployeeTable(results) {
  const { data } = MyData

  return (
      <div class="container-fluid" class="row" fluid={true}>
          {
            data.Table.map(results =>
              <div class="col-sm-3" key={results.Employee_Number}>
                <div class="card our-team" >
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">{results.first_name}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{results.last_name}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
              </div>
            )
          }
      </div>
  );
}
```

I didn't use `static` but you can of course...

I don't think you really need this bit:

```
async populateemployeeData() {
    const response = await fetch('table');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ results: data, loading: false });
}
```

in the component did mount you are making that request and setting it to state, you should move the `isLoading` up to the `componentDidMount` while you are awaiting the data... you can do something like (SUPER loosely coded so it probably won't run without some syntax corrections)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    results: [],
    isLoading: null 
  };
}

componentDidMount () {
  this.setState({isLoading: true})

  fetch('http://web.api.services/api/v2/tultula/employees/all', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'api-key': 'xxx-xxx-xxx'  
    }
    })
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(data => this.setState(
      { 
        isLoading: false, 
        results: data 
      })
    );
}


function renderemployeeTable() {
  const { isLoading, results } = this.state
  const {Table: table} = results
  return (
    { isLoading 
      ? <SomeLoadingComponetThingie /> 
      :  <div class="container-fluid" class="row" fluid={true}>
          {
            table.map(results =>
              <div class="col-sm-3" key={results.Employee_Number}>
                <div class="card our-team" >
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">{results.first_name}</p>
                    <p class="card-text">{results.last_name}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
              </div>
            )
          }
          </div>
    }
  );
}

render() {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="tabelLabel" >-</h1>
        {renderemployeeTable()}
      </div>
  );

}
```

This is meant to be a general idea. 1) basically you set the `isLoading` first in the componentDidMount - thus while the page is fetching you will see the loader (idk if you have a component for that i made one up) 
2) once the data is fetched and set to `state` and toggle the isLoading to false... setting state will trigger a re-render and display the component with the data since isLoading is now false. You should of course, do some checks and have a plan for if the data does not come back, you get a server error or whatever. you can also use a conditional checking if `Table` exists and has a length before turning the loader off (you could switch it out with a error message for example - lots of options on how you want to handle the unexpected.

EDIT: looking back at this you may need to put the conditional `isLoading` and a check for `results` in the render for this to update (re-render) once the state updates ;)

Comment: this can also be cleaned up a bit but to keep it straightforward i didn't :)

Comment: Thank you so much but how can i convert this to fetch from the url?

Comment: you are actually pretty close what you have should work but you don't need that call at the bottom, give me a second and i will update my answer more....

Comment: updated, and it's meant to be a guideline - it may not run as-is since i could not run it locally and i often make syntax errors LOL

Comment: also, if i answered your ORIGINAL question on iterating the `Table` (which i did in the comments on your question ;) lol... then kindly mark the answer as answered.... this bit is extra credit! haha

Comment: also note, i have used an `async` componentDidMount before but IDK if it's good practice, it would be ideal to `await` that api call (and even wrap it in a `try/catch` block) ...but did not attempt to do it in this example (and add complexity) and instead relied on the fact that the results of that fetch set `state` and `state` will trigger a re-render and _should_ work

Comment: i sure will, you the best!

Comment: It doesn’t work when trying to access it ‘results.data.Table((results, index)=>... I get “can not read property Table”

Comment: Then log results, you may be having a server error or the request is bad (check the request in your dev tools network tab). If results comes back with something other than an error look at it and see if it has data... If it has data, look for Table... Either you are having a problem with the request/response or the response isn't giving you the data you expect (idk if that's for a specific day or all days or what)

Comment: I checked the api request log it has error 401 I get response status 200 when i use postman postman returns

Comment: I also have to use cors chrome addon to run api

Comment: 401 is a auth error. Usually a bad API key, or you are passing it incorrectly. Idk what changed in your code or what you are doing differently? Cuz this worked yesterday lol